# Group by key, file partition

Tags: shell, mapreduce

I'm looking for a shell approach to a more-efficient-than-global-sort group-by-key action on a file. In particular, I would like to split a file based on the value of a key (so that all lines starting with the same key end up in the same file). (This command would then be the first step, followed by sorting these partitioned files, for example.)

This can be done in a single pass of the file by doing something like, e.g. hashing the key modulo some parameter corresponding to the maximum number of partition files that would result.

Curious whether there any command which can do something like this?

(E.g. if the keys are just single characters, the crucial point is that "all" Bs and Ds end up in file1, all Ac and Cs end up in file2 etc. so that after sorted those files, we know that all of the like keys are grouped with one another. One motivation here is to demonstrate the hash-partitioning of map-reduce with a shell command.)

Comment: If you share a example it will be more clear for some help.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. The two sample output files don't match the input file you give, do they? 10 is a parameter, and you want each key to only appear in one of the output files?

Comment: Yes, this is just a partition function so each key appears in exactly one of the files: that's the only requirement; 10 is a best-effort parameter (if all of the keys are the same, there can only be one nonempty file, for example; if there are only two keys, at most two nonempty files).

Answer (score 1):

Ignore your parameter, the key file creation is very straightforward.

Get all unique keys from the file:

```
unique_keys=`cut -f1 ${input_file} | sort -u`
```

find each of the keys in the original file and put each of them in its own index file:

```
for key in $unique_keys
do
    grep "^${key} " ${input_file} >> ${key}_index
done
```

That will leave you with files like

A_index

```
A value4
A value1
A value2
```

B_index

```
B value2
B value3
```

C_index

```
C value5
```

and so on.

Instead of using some fixed value to group the indices, it probably makes more sense to limit the index file line count to keep them relatively similar.

```
current_index=0
current_file="${key}_${current_index}"
for key in $unique_key
do
    # add key to index file
    grep "^${key} " ${input_file} >> "${current_file}"
    # check if the max line count is exceeded
    line_count=$(wc -l <"${current_file}")
    if [ $line_count -ge $max_lines ]
    then
        # line count exceeded, update index and index file name
        current_index=$((current_index+1))
        current_file="${key}_${current_index}"
    fi
done
```

I'm sure this can be done much shorter, but I guess it's more important to be understandable for a beginner.

Comment: Interesting approach with grep although I was really looking for something that wasn't just a script. This involves passing over the file around #keys times (rather than, say, once) so probably isn't the more efficient way to script it (compared with say, one pass and appending lines to a file related to a hash of the key).